# String.split not working as intended

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, split

this is driving me absolutely nuts! i've done some error testing already, and i really don't know how to proceed right now.

i'm reading from a text file, splitting the line with the String.split(",") method (i'm using a comma), and doing stuff with the data. I'm having trouble... i'm getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

This is the first two lines of my file:

```
1,,1,Male Slave,,1,1,
2,yes,1,Bronze Cooking Pot,,,,
```

my code:

```
        try {       
        File file = new File("/Accounts/changy/Desktop/GreekProject/data.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        sc.nextLine(); 
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            String[] splitArray = line.split(",{1}");
            System.out.println(splitArray.length);
            System.out.println(splitArray[0] + "\t" + splitArray[1] + "\t" + splitArray[2]+ "\t" + splitArray[3]+ "\t" + splitArray[4]);
        }
    }        
    catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("NPE!!");
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("FNFE!!");
    }
    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("AIOOBE!!")
    }
```

so if i omit splitArray[4], the code runs perfectly fine. I've even tried adding additional commas at the end of the line, and that doesn't help. The length of the array is 7, so it really doesn't make sense to me that fifth entry is empty... any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of the `split` method with only one argument will trim all empty token strings off the end of the array before returning it to you, so the second line will yield an array of length only 4.

Use the [two-argument version of `split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), with a negative `limit`, so that it will not trim trailing empty strings off the array, and all expected elements will be there.

```
String[] splitArray = line.split(",{1}", -1);
```

Quoting from the linked Javadocs:

> If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as
>   possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero then the
>   pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have
>   any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

Here, when they refer to `n`, they really are referring to `limit` (the second parameter).

Comment: thanks for your response, now it works as desired! However, i still have one question - when i do array.length to the splitArray, the length it returned was 7, even though it should return 4... which is why i never suspected it's trimming trailing separators. do you know why this is, or should i just let it be and move on?

Answer (score 3):

`String.split` silently discards trailing separators.  (This is one of its many, many issues.)  IIRC, you should get the desired behavior with `line.split(",{1}", -1);`.